# Add image into UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone

How to Add image into UIActionSheet?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet{

UIImageView* df = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourpic.png"]];
df.center

[actionSheet addSubview:df];
//scale image aspect to fit image view
df.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//change width of frame
CGRect frame = df.frame;
frame.size.width = 50;
df.frame = frame;

}
```

It will resize it as shown.

Comment: The `df.center` line doesn't compile. I tried `df.center = actionSheet.center;` but still no image appeared.